# Ajustar tabla html

Tags: html, css

Buen día, quisiera hacer este diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente `html`:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
 <td><img src="${img_limits}" /></td>
 <td>Productividad</td>
 <td><span class="pg-normal">›</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td><img src="${img_ric}" /></td>
 <td>Incentivación</td>
 <td><span class="pg-normal">›</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Pero lo que tengo es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podría ajustar la tabla para que quede parecido al primer diseño?.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Algun motivo en particular para usar una tabla especificamente para ese diseño?

Comment: No, ninguno en especial, se podría hacer de otra forma.

Comment: La cuestión es que sí lo haces en tablas pues la tecnología no es tan buena... hace muchísimo tiempo el diseño web se quitaron. Obvio aún se usan tablas pero no para las maquetaciones.

Answer (score 6):

No suelo promover utilizar tablas para crear elementos que no son precisamente para mostrar *informacion tabular*, en este caso, ya que se esta construyendo un panel con opciones, prefiero utilizar otros elementos mas sencillos y flexibles para personalizar.

Haciendo uso de flexbox es bastante sencillo alinear elementos y aprovechando las propiedades por defecto de elementos bloque se puede obtener un resultado muy similar al que necesitas.

```css
.panel {
  width: 200px;
}

.panel-header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1465a6;
}

.panel-header span {
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.panel-header button {
  background-color: #063263;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-header button span {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.panel-content .item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.panel-content .item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-header">
    <span>Como voy?</span>
    <button>
      <span>&bull;</span>
      <span>&bull;</span>
      <span>&bull;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="">
      <span>Incentivacion</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="">
      <span>Productividad</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="">
      <span>Incentivacion</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paula lograste resolver el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que mostrar tu CSS y HTML completo si es que tenes uno creado, sino deberias crearlo y ponerle class a las etiquetas para darle los estilos que buscas (EJ: `<div class="titulo"> .`

y luego en tu css podras hacer :

```
.titulo {
      color:white;
}
```

y modificar los estilos que necesites.

Por otro lado tenes invertido los titulos segun el ejemplo al que quieres llegar y el que estas armando. Me refiero a que actualmente dice:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="${img_limits}" /></td>
    <td>Productividad</td>
    <td><span class="pg-normal">›</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="${img_ric}" /></td>
    <td>Incentivación</td>
    <td><span class="pg-normal">›</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

y deberia ser:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="${img_limits}" /></td>
    <td>Incentivación</td>
    <td><span class="pg-normal">›</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="${img_ric}" /></td>
    <td>Productividad</td>
    <td><span class="pg-normal">›</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```